# DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object

Tags: apex, trigger

This trigger fires after inserting a User. It will create a new record on Leave_Balance_Transaction__c  but Im encountering this error:

> Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger
>   autoCreateLBT4NewEmploy caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: autoCreateLBT4NewEmploy: execution of AfterInsert
>   caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row
>   0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is
>   not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice
>   versa): Leave_Balance_Transaction__c, original object: User: []:
>   Trigger.autoCreateLBT4NewEmploy: line 30, column 1

```
trigger autoCreateLBT4NewEmploy on User (after insert) {
    List <Id> ids = new List<Id>();
    Set<Id> Cids = new Set<Id>();
    List <Leave_Balance_Transaction__c> newLbT4newUser = new List<Leave_Balance_Transaction__c>();    
    List <Contact> tmpContact = new List<Contact>();
    List <User> tmpUser = new List<User>();

    for(User userID : Trigger.NEW) {
        ids.add(userID.id);
        Cids.add(userID.ContactId);    
    }    

    for(Contact con : [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE id IN : Cids AND no_of_years__c > 0]){
        if(con != null){
            tmpContact.add(con);
        }
    }

    for(User user1 : [SELECT ID, ContactId FROM User WHERE ContactId IN : tmpContact]){            
         newLbT4newUser.add(new Leave_Balance_Transaction__c( 
             employee__c = user1.id,
             active__c = 'Active'));      
             //
    }
    insert newLbT4newUser;        
}
```

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: use future method to resolve mix dml error..  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm'

Comment: can you give me a sample code for future if thats okay

Comment: Please see - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm . This will help

Comment: It shows how to use the future method to avoid this. Another way is - you could query out the current user after getting his ID for UserInfo.getUserId() . Then do the part about inserting user inside a runAs(currentUser) block. That is easier.

Comment: Made my day :) . Cheers

Comment: is there any way rather than using @future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks into this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm).

For mix dml error use future method so it will solve the issue.

Mix dml error occurs when a non setup and setup object updated/inserted in same transaction then mix dml occurs.

We can avoid this error using future method.

Created a class with future method

```
public class createLeaveBalTransClass
{
    @future 
    public static void createLeaveBalTrans(set<Id> setContactids)
    {
        List <Leave_Balance_Transaction__c> newLbT4newUser = new List<Leave_Balance_Transaction__c>();    
        for(User user1 : [SELECT ID, ContactId FROM User WHERE ContactId IN : setContactids]){

              newLbT4newUser.add(new Leave_Balance_Transaction__c( 
              employee__c = user1.id,
              active__c = 'Active'));
        }
        insert newLbT4newUser;   
    }
}
```

now in trigger collect all contacts Id

```
createLeaveBalTransClass.createLeaveBalTrans(setContactids);
```

Comment: hi ratan can you teach me how to summon @future class into trigger? If its okay

Comment: @gelay I don't think you can do that because we can't create method in trigger it self that's why you need to create another class with future method and call that method from trigger and pass the set of contact Ids.. this way it will work..

Comment: is there any way rather than using @future?

Comment: @gelay I say no.. This is the only solution

Comment: how can i get the Trigger.new in the class?

Comment: @gelay simple just pass Trigger.New as a parameter in class method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39168/discussion-between-gelay-and-ratan).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `User` is a setup object and you can not insert a non-setup object records after inserting the setup object records so you have to do this asynchronously.

See [Setup objects in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_setup.htm)

check this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wAZIAY